# Removing a view controller from UIPageViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

It's odd that there's no straightforward way to do this. Consider the following scenario:

1. You have a page view controller with 1 page.
2. Add another page (total 2) and scroll to it.
3. **What I want is,** when the user scrolls back to the first page, the 2nd page is now removed and deallocated, and the user can no longer swipe back to that page.

I've tried removing the view controller as a child view controller after the transition is completed, but it still lets me scroll back to the empty page (it doesn't "resize" the page view)

Is what I want to do possible?

Comment: There actually is a straightforward way, just set the data source again, see user1459524's answer.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

While the answers here are all informative, there is an alternate way of handling the problem, given here:

[UIPageViewController navigates to wrong page with Scroll transition style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939280/uipageviewcontroller-navigates-to-wrong-page-with-scroll-transition-style)

When I first searched for an answer to this problem, the way I was wording my search wound me up at this question, and not the one I've just linked to, so I felt obligated to post an answer linking to this other question, now that I've found it, and also elaborating a little bit.

The problem is described pretty well by matt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12939384/700471):

> This is actually a bug in UIPageViewController. It occurs only with the scroll style (UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll) and only
>   after calling setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion: with
>   animated:YES. Thus there are two workarounds:
>
> Don't use UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll.
>
> Or, if you call setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:, use
>   only animated:NO.
>
> To see the bug clearly, call
>   setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion: and then, in the
>   interface (as user), navigate left (back) to the preceding page
>   manually. You will navigate back to the wrong page: not the preceding
>   page at all, but the page you were on when
>   setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion: was called.
>
> The reason for the bug appears to be that, when using the scroll
>   style, UIPageViewController does some sort of internal caching. Thus,
>   after the call to setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:,
>   it fails to clear its internal cache. It thinks it knows what the
>   preceding page is. Thus, when the user navigates leftward to the
>   preceding page, UIPageViewController fails to call the dataSource
>   method pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:, or
>   calls it with the wrong current view controller.

This is a good description, not quite the problem noted in this question but very close.  Note the line about if you do `setViewControllers` with `animated:NO` you will force the UIPageViewController to re-query its data source next time the user pans with a gesture, as it no longer "knows where it is" or what view controllers are next to its current view controller.

However, this didn't work for me because there were times when I need to programmatically move the PageView around *with* an animation.

So, my first thought was to call `setViewControllers` with an animation, and then in the completion block call the method again with whatever view controller was now showing, but with no animation.  So the user can pan, fine, but then we call the method again to get the page view to reset.

Unfortunately when I tried that I started getting strange "assertion errors" from the page view controller.  They look something like this:

> *** Assertion failure in -[UIPageViewController queuingScrollView: ...

Not knowing exactly why this was happening, I backtracked and eventually started using [Jai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16308151/700471) as a solution, creating an entirely new UIPageViewController, pushing it onto a UINavigationController, then popping out the old one.  Gross, but it works--mostly.  I have been finding I'm still getting occasional Assertion Failures from the UIPageViewController, like this one:

> *** Assertion failure in -[UIPageViewController queuingScrollView:didEndManualScroll:toRevealView:direction:animated:didFinish:didComplete:],
>   /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UIPageViewController.m:1820 $1 =
>   154507824 No view controller managing visible view >

And the app crashes.  Why?  Well, searching, I found this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939280/uipageviewcontroller-navigates-to-wrong-page-with-scroll-transition-style) that I mentioned up top, and particularly the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13253884/700471) which advocates my original idea, of simply calling `setViewControllers: animated:YES` and then as soon as it completes calling `setViewControllers: animated:NO` with the same view controllers to reset the UIPageViewController, but it had the missing element: calling that code back on the main queue!  Here's the code:

```
__weak YourSelfClass *blocksafeSelf = self;     
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished){
            if(finished)
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [blocksafeSelf.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:NULL];// bug fix for uipageview controller
                });
            }
        }];
```

Wow!  The only reason this actually made sense to me is because I have watched the the WWDC 2012 Session 211, Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS (available [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) with a dev account).  I recall now that attempting to modify data source objects that UIKit objects (like UIPageViewController) depend on, and doing it on a secondary queue, can cause some nasty crashes.

What I have never seen particularly documented, but must now assume to be the case and read up on, is that the completion block for an animation is performed on a secondary queue, not the main one.  So the reason why UIPageViewController was squawking and giving assertion failures, both when I originally attempted to call `setViewControllers animated:NO` in the completion block of `setViewControllers animated:YES` and also now that I am simply using a UINavigationController to push on a new UIPageViewController (but doing it, again, in the completion block of `setViewControllers animated:YES`) is because it's all happening on that secondary queue.

That's why that piece of code up there works perfectly, because you come from the animation completion block and send it back over to the main queue so you don't cross the streams with UIKit.  Brilliant.

Anyway, wanted to share this journey, in case anyone runs across this problem.

EDIT: Swift version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33786397/700471), if anyone's interested.

Comment: Thanks for a really detailed answer! This helped me solve my problem, which, however, was a bit different from the original question.

Comment: I'd like to add, I'm using a UIPageViewController with fairly heavyweight views (containing various scroll and collection views).  While this solution did reduce these crashes, it didn't eliminate them entirely.  Using breakpoints, I found that there was some lag between when the view controller began the auto scroll process and when the completion block was called.  If the view was touched during this time, the app would crash.  Overriding hitTest didn't work, so I just did [AppDelegate myapp].window.userInteractionEnabled = NO, and re-enabled user interaction in the completion block.

Comment: @VanDuTran Two questions: what version of iOS are you running, and what happens if you *only* call `setViewControllers` with `animated:NO`, with no completion block?  Does that "break the cache" so to speak?

Comment: @MattMc I actually found out the bug.. I didn't update my "currentVC" to point to the new current view controller.. it was still pointing to the deleted view controller. However, I did not need to use your trick at all! I call setViewControllers with animated:true and it works! Weird. iOS 8.4 Xcode 6.4

Comment: @VanDuTran Glad you worked it out.  And hey, perhaps Apple fixed this!  That would be great.  :)

Comment: @MattMc, Are you sure that in "__block YourSelfClass *blocksafeSelf = self;" _block is appropriate? It should be __weak

Comment: @malex Thanks for pointing that out.  Yes, `__weak` is more appropriate here.  The two keywords have rather different uses, which I had to clarify for myself just now.  Avoiding a potential retain cycle is done with `__weak`.  Thanks again!

Comment: @MattMc could you please post your solution in Swift or answer my question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742522/background-images-on-pageviewcontroller-overlap-in-reverse?  I tried to convert it but wasn't able to...I couldn't figure out what was going on with the blocksafeSelf line...

Comment: @PSUSabes Took a stab at a [Swift version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33786397/700471) for ya.

Comment: Starting w/ iOS10,  [Matt Mc's code above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17330606/3670756) has an issue if the setViewControllers workaround is called twice quickly w/ different viewControllers.  The UIPageViewController will render in between pages, with a section of the page missing.  You may need to be on a physical device to reproduce the bug.

Comment: Hi, really good answer. I saw this here and was wondering if this might be an easier alternative if you want to still animate? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21624169/6567876

Answer (score 8):

Concluding Matt Mc's great answer, the following method could be added to a subclass of UIPageViewController, that way allowing the usage of setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion: as it was intended to be used if the bug would not be present.

```
- (void) setViewControllers:(NSArray*)viewControllers direction:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection)direction animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(BOOL))completion {

    if (!animated) {
        [super setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:direction animated:NO completion:completion];
        return;
    }

    [super setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:direction animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished){

        if (finished) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [super setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:direction animated:NO completion:completion];
            });
        } else {
            if (completion != NULL) {
                completion(finished);
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Now, simply call setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion: on the class/subclasses implementing this method, and it should work as expected.

Comment: Would probably be improved by adding `completion(finished);` in an `else` block for `if (finished)` to make sure your completion block gets called.

Comment: @Ned Thanks! I have now changed the code to also cover that case.

Answer (score 5):

maq is right. If you are using the scrolling transition, removing a child view controller from the UIPageViewController does not prevent the deleted "page" from returning on-screen if the user navigates to it. If you're interested, here's how I removed the child view controller from the UIPageViewController.

```
// deleteVC is a child view controller of the UIPageViewController
[deleteVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[deleteVC.view removeFromSuperview];
[deleteVC removeFromParentViewController];
```

View controller deleteVC is removed from the childViewControllers property of the UIPageViewController, but still appears on-screen if the user navigates to it.

Until someone smarter than me finds an elegant solution, here's a work around (it's a hack--so you have to ask yourself if you really need to remove pages from a UIPageViewController).

These instructions assume that only one page is displayed at a time.

After the user taps a button indicating that she would like to delete the page, navigate to the next or previous page using the setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion: method. Of course, you then need to delete the page's content from your data model.

Next (and here's the hack), create and configure a brand new UIPageViewController and load it in the foreground (i.e., in front of the other UIPageViewController).  Make sure that the new UIPageViewController starts off displaying the exact same page that was previously displayed. Your new UIPageViewController will fetch fresh view controllers from the data source.

Finally, unload and destroy the UIPageViewController that's in the background.

Anyway, maq asked a really good question. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation points to up vote the question. Ah, dare to dream... someday I will have 15 reputation points.

Comment: Trying to do this, except the new UIPageViewController doesn't display a page after I add it into the view hierarchy and call the container-controller methods, and call setViewControllers. It only fills content in the pages *after* you start panning with a gesture. Encounter anything like this?

Comment: This solved my problem of closing a PageViewController completely. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

I'll put this answer here just for my own future reference and if it helps anyone - what I ended up doing was:

1. Delete the page and advance to the next page
2. In the completion block of `setViewControllers`, I created/init'ed a new UIPageViewController with the modified data (item removed), and pushed it without animating, so nothing changes on-screen (my UIPageViewController is contained within a UINavigationController)
3. After pushing the new UIPageViewController, get a copy of the `viewControllers` array of the UINavigationController, remove the second-to-last view controller (which is the old UIPageViewController)
4. There is no step 4 - done!

Comment: Dear lord, it took me nearly 8 hours to solve a scenario where I needed to dynamically alter a UIPageViewController's pages! The solution you provided here finally did the trick--wish I could upvote you multiple times! :D

Comment: Now you see why I posted it here for my own reference lol...glad it helped someone else too!

Answer (score 3):

I am just learning this myself, so take with a grain of salt, but from what I understand, you need to change the datasource of the pageviewcontroller, not remove the viewcontroller. How many pages are shown in a pageviewcontroller is determined by its datasource, not the viewcontrollers.

Comment: Correct, simply set a new datasource and the deleted controller is gone

Comment: To keep the same dataSource, set it to nil, then back to the original

Answer (score 2):

For improve this. You should detect whether pageView is scrolling or not before setViewControllers.

```
var isScrolling = false

func viewDidLoad() {
...

  for v in view.subviews{
    if v.isKindOfClass(UIScrollView) {
      (v as! UIScrollView).delegate = self
    }
  }
}

func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView){
    isScrolling = true
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView){
    isScrolling = false
}

func jumpToVC{
    if isScrolling {  //you should not jump out when scrolling
        return
    }
    setViewControllers([vc], direction:direction, animated:true, completion:{[unowned self] (succ) -> Void in
        if succ {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.setViewControllers([vc], direction:direction, animated:false, completion:nil)
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem exists when you are trying to change viewControllers during swipe gesture animation between viewControllers. To solve this problem, i made a simple flag to discover when page view controller is during transition.

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray *)pendingViewControllers {
    self.pageViewControllerTransitionInProgress = YES;
}

- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed {
        self.pageViewControllerTransitionInProgress = NO;
}
```

And when i am trying to chenge view controller i am checking if there is transition in progress.

```
- (void)setCurrentPage:(NSString *)newCurrentPageId animated:(BOOL)animated {

    if (self.pageViewControllerTransitionInProgress) {
        return;
    }

    [self.pageContentViewController setViewControllers:@[pageDetails] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually I think I solved the issue. This is what was happening in my app:

1. UIViewController subclass instance was removed from UIPageViewController by removing it from model and setting viewControllers property of UIPageViewController to different ViewController. This is enough to do the job. No need to do any controller containment code on that controller
2. The ViewController was gone, but I could still scroll to it by swiping right in my case.
3. My issue was this. I was adding a custom gesture recognizer to ViewController displayed by UIPageViewController. This recognizer was hold as a strong property on the controller that also owned UIPageViewController.
4. FIX: **before loosing access to the ViewController being dismissed I made sure I properly cleaned all the memory it uses(dealloc) and removed the gesture recognizer**
5. Your mileage may vary, but I see no point for this solution to be wrong, when something's not working I first suspect my code :)

Comment: So I was using a paging library that cached the view controllers. Rewrote it to get them released at UIPageViewController's whim, but still facing the problems :/

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar situation where I wanted the user to be able to "tap and delete" any page from the UIPageViewController. After playing a bit with it, I found a simpler solution than the ones described above:

1. Capture the page index of the "dying page".
2. Check to see if the "dying page" is the last page.

   - This is important because if it is the last page, we need to scroll left (if we have pages "A B C" and delete C, we will scroll to B).
   - If it is not the last page, we will scroll right (if we have pages "A B C" and delete B, we will scroll to C).
3. Make a temporary jump to a "safe" place (ideally the final one). Use animated: NO to have this happen instantaneously.

   ```
   UIViewController *jumpToAnotherViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:dyingPageIndex-1];
   [self setViewControllers:@[jumpToAnotherViewController] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:NO completion:nil];
   ```
4. Delete the selected page from the model/datasource.
5. Now, if it is the last page:

   - Adjust your model to select the page on the left.
   - Get the viewcontroller on the left, note that THIS IS THE SAME ONE than the one you retrieved in step 3.
   - It is important to do this AFTER you have deleted the page from the datasource because it will refresh it.
   - Jump to it, this time with animated: YES.

     ```
     jumpToAnotherViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:dyingPageIndex-1];
     [self setViewControllers:@[jumpToAnotherViewController] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:YES completion:nil];
     ```
6. In the case where it was NOT the last page:

   - Adjust your model to select the page on the right.
   - Get the viewcontroller on the right, note that this is not the one you retrieved in step 3. In my case, you will see that it is the one at dyingPageIndex, because the dying page has already been removed from the model.
   - Again, it is important to do this AFTER you have deleted the page from the datasource because it will refresh it.
   - Jump to it, this time with animated: YES.

     ```
     jumpToAnotherViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:dyingPageIndex;
     [self setViewControllers:@[jumpToAnotherViewController] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];
     ```
7. That's it! This works well in XCode 6.1.1.

Full code below. This code is in my UIPageViewController and is called through a delegate from the page to be deleted. In my case, deleting the first page was not allowed as it contains different things from the rest of the pages. Of course, you need to substitute:

- YourUIViewController: with the class of your individual pages.
- YourTotalNumberOfPagesFromModel: with the total number of pages in your model
- [YourModel deletePage:] with the code to delete the dying page from your model

  ```
  - (void)deleteAViewController:(id)sender {
      YourUIViewController *dyingGroup = (YourUIViewController *)sender;
      NSUInteger dyingPageIndex = dyingGroup.pageIndex;
      // Check to see if we are in the last page as it's a special case.
      BOOL isTheLastPage = (dyingPageIndex >= YourTotalNumberOfPagesFromModel.count);
      // Make a temporary jump back - make sure to use animated:NO to have it jump instantly
      UIViewController *jumpToAnotherViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:dyingPageIndex-1];
      [self setViewControllers:@[jumpToAnotherViewController] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:NO completion:nil];
      // Now delete the selected group from the model, setting the target
      [YourModel deletePage:dyingPageIndex];
      if (isTheLastPage) {
          // Now jump to the definitive controller. In this case, it's the same one, we're just reloading it to refresh the data source.
          // This time we're using animated:YES
          jumpToAnotherViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:dyingPageIndex-1];
          [self setViewControllers:@[jumpToAnotherViewController] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:YES completion:nil];
      } else {
          // Now jump to the definitive controller. This reloads the data source. This time we're using animated:YES
          jumpToAnotherViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:dyingPageIndex];
          [self setViewControllers:@[jumpToAnotherViewController] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSMutableArray *mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.userArray];
[mArray removeObject:userToBlock];
self.userArray = mArray;

UIViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:atIndex-1];
NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:NO completion:nil];
```

I didn't quite have time to read through the above comments but this worked for me. Basically I remove the data (in my case a user) and then move to the page before it. Works like a charm. Hope this helps those looking for a quick fix.

Answer (score -1):

It did it the following in Swift 3.0

```
fileprivate var isAnimated:Bool = false

override func setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController]?, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection, animated: Bool, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {

        if self.isAnimated {
            delay(0.5, closure: { 
                self.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: direction, animated: animated, completion: completion)
            })
        }else {
                super.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: direction, animated: animated, completion: completion)
        }

    }


extension SliderViewController:UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
        self.isAnimated = true
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        self.isAnimated = finished
    }
}
```

And here the delay function

```
func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(
        deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: closure)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

we are getting crash on tab change .So one solution i got is didChangeSelect of tabs disable the userintraction.