# Remove PageViewController

Tags: ios, view, uipageviewcontroller

I've used a tutorial on AppCoda for adding a sort of tutorial style UIPageViewController - it works amazingly - it's just that I can't remove it on a button click.

Here's my PageViewController:

```
#import "startupViewController.h"
#import "SKSlideViewController.h"
#import "APPChildViewController.h"

@interface startupViewController ()
@end
@implementation startupViewController
@synthesize outletWallpaper;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self mymethod];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)mymethod {

    self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

    self.pageController.dataSource = self;
    [[self.pageController view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];

    APPChildViewController *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];

    [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
    [[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
    [self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}

- (APPChildViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    APPChildViewController *childViewController = [[APPChildViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"APPChildViewController" bundle:nil];
    childViewController.index = index;

    return childViewController;

}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [(APPChildViewController *)viewController index];

    if (index == 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Decrease the index by 1 to return
    index--;

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];

}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [(APPChildViewController *)viewController index];

    index++;

    if (index == 3) {
        return nil;
    }

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];

}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    // The number of items reflected in the page indicator.
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    // The selected item reflected in the page indicator.
    return 0;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"Switching View Controllers...");

        SKSlideViewController *slideController=(SKSlideViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        [slideController setStoryBoardIDForMainController:@"MainVC" leftController:@"LeftVC" rightController:@"RightVC"];
        [slideController reloadControllers];

}

@end
```

This code sends me to another file which from there, I need to remove the whole thing.

Comment: I've tried removing everything from the SuperView, nothing works. But I tried setting the self.view.alpha to 0 (on the new .m file it links to), that seems to work, but anything underneath (buttons etc..) I cannot use for some reason?

Comment: Loop through all views in your view, superview, maybe childview and find your pageController first.

Comment: I've just tried adding this code to UIPageController.m:

- (IBAction)closeAll:(id)sender {
    
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainVC"];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
    
}



It now says: Attempt to present <SAMainViewController: 0x8d37a40> on <startupViewController: 0x8d2c740> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!?

Comment: And the reason the buttons underneath don't work is because the UIPageController is still there.

Comment: Try setting the frame to be CGRectZero

Answer (score 0):

I think I did the same tutorial on [appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/), and had the same question!

A solution that has worked for me I stumbled across accidentally on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14847951/6340):

```
// Replace deleteVC with your UIPageViewController
[deleteVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[deleteVC.view removeFromSuperview];
[deleteVC removeFromParentViewController];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var movingIndex = 0
var forwardDirection = false

    if selectedIndex == images.count{ //ur pages dataSource You may not need this
            movingIndex = selectedIndex - 1
            forwardDirection = false
        } else {
            movingIndex = selectedIndex
            forwardDirection = true
        }
    
    controllers.remove(at: selectedIndex)
    capturedInspectionPhotoView.imagePageController?.dataSource = self
    capturedInspectionPhotoView.imagePageController?.setViewControllers([controllers[movingIndex]],
                                            direction: forwardDirection ? .forward : .reverse, animated: true)
```